# Did django use thread to handle requests?

Tags: django

what is the underlying infrastructure  Django uses to handle its requests?

did it use thread, can someone give some reference on this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django is not a web server. It is a web framework. The behavior of how it is being run as an application is dependant on your method for serving it.

It could be threaded requests. It could be processes. It could even be async.

[Serving Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files)

> Django doesn't serve files itself; it leaves that job to whichever Web server you choose.

Wsgi is the most common way to serve django right now, so really you should just investigate the configuration options of different wsgi implementations.

Comment: well, you can say that. I was thinking django did provide itself away to run the webapp: manage.py runserver

Comment: actually, *Django is not a web server.* is this the reason why people down the question?

Comment: `manage.py runserver` is the convenience dev server that is bundled with django. It is NOT for production. I'm guessing the downvotes were for maybe not knowing it isnt a server?

Answer (score 1):

If you get random segmentation faults when using `manage.py runserver` because some underlying C libraries you have to use in your project are not thread-safe, try 

`manage.py runserver --nothreading`

instead.

---

For production services that run wsgi with tools like `mod_wsgi`, there is usually an option to disable threading. In this case 

`WSGIDaemonProcess example processes=5 threads=1`

See https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/processes-and-threading.html