# Importance of concurrency issues in web applications

Tags: concurrency

With respect to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487822/concurrency-issues-in-web-applications), is it always necessary to have perfectly concurrent-safe web-application or can a developer afford to let some possible concurrent issues untreated (e.g. when money is not involved) because probability of them happening is very low anyway. What is the best practice?

NOTE: If I say concurrent issues I mean the issues raising from overlapping executions of scripts. I do not mean the multi-user issues like classic lost-update with the timestamp solution cause probability of these things is imho significant and I am pretty sure here that the best practice is to always treat them.

Comment: That's way too general to be answerable. It always depends on the issue whether an issue is an issue or may be not so important.

Comment: @deceze it is a question about common practice, to which general answers and guidelines are perfectly possible.  I agree that it's not a very specific question, but many interesting questions are not.

Comment: @deceze i know it is general but if you think about it - you have provided a solid answer with your second sentence. The answer of thebjorn says the opposite to what you said, which means there is something to talk about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to run your code on a web server, you should always write your code in such a way that multiple copies of it can run at the same time.

It's really not that difficult.  In most cases database transactions around state modifying operations is all that is needed (or using a lock file, or any of the other well-known solutions to this problem).

Note: if all you're doing is reading data then there are no concurrency issues.

Comment: I am also of the opinion the code should generally be correct in every possible way. At the same time, I find this concurrency stuff to be very hard to think about - i always try to think of some scenario where things can go wrong and after I find it, I take an appropriate actions to prevent it (for db matters, i usually use select for update or select locked in shared mode in a innodb repeatable-read transactions). However, this procedure takes a lot of time and sometimes i know it is of very low importancy for the system. But thinking about what is important and what is not is painful too...