# Does Django use processes or threads to handle user requests in view?

Tags: django

Does **Django** use processes or threads to handle user requests in view?

If Django uses threads I can't to use all CPU cores(python global interpreter lock), if Django uses processes I can't with no worry share memory.

I tried to find the info in google, but maximum that I have managed to find is [Did django use thread to handle requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425374/did-django-use-thread-to-handle-requests) This seems isn't a answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Django is run as a WSGI application. How that happens is determined by your WSGI server (e.g. uWSGI, Gunicorn, mod_wsgi).

Django's request handler is thread-safe. You can configure your WSGI server to use any number of processes (sometimes called workers) and threads per process.

As you've mentioned, processes use more memory, but threads are affected by the GIL. A good configuration should find a balance between the number of processes and the number of threads per process.

Comment: Could I make concurrent safe Processes Pool, and make request to that pool from views? (I need to distribute my computing) Are any ways for that?  Python multiprocessing.pool (How it written in doc) can be accessed only from one process.

Comment: @SeregaLuchko Maybe you're looking for a task queue like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)?

Comment: As already suggested, if trying to offload tasks triggered by a request then look at a queueing system such as Celery. For a general discussion of how processes/threads work in a WSGI server such as mod_wsgi see http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/processes-and-threading.html

Comment: Thank you Graham for you addition. Link about wsgi provided by you is very useful.