# Does Django run multiple threads or processes?

Tags: django, multithreading, multiprocessing

When Django is in production (e.g. sitting behind nginx or something) Does it spawn itself multiple threads to handle requests or processes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359077/does-django-use-processes-or-threads-to-handle-user-requests-in-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you will use something like Gunicorn (third party software) to help serve your Django app.

Gunicorn can spawn multiple processes. For a basic app setup, most people use three.

So, yes. Your app will probably be served by multiple workers behind nginx.